# Intercept JAX-RS web service response to add JSON field

Tags: json, web-services, jax-rs, weblogic12c

I have a JAX-RS web service that returns a Response object as shown below (it is running in WebLogic 12.2.1). It will return a JSON response to the client. Is it possible to write an interceptor or filter, such that when the web service call is returned, it will add an extra field in the JSON response?

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("LogIn")
public Response logIn(@Context HttpServletRequest request, Parameters requestParameters) {...}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which implementation of JAX-RS are you using? If Jersey then you can try implementing `ContainerResponseFilter`.
On Over-riding `filter()`, it provides 'ContainerResponseContext' object which gives you access to the response that is being sent using `getEntity()` method. You can modify this object and set it back in the response.

Comment: I am using Jersey. I tried your suggestion. It works. Thanks a lot! Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: I've updated it as answer. Please accept it, if worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Jersey, then you can try implementing `ContainerResponseFilter`.

On Over-riding `filter()`, it provides `ContainerResponseContext` object which gives you access to the response that is being sent using `getEntity()` method.

You can modify this object and set it back in the response.

```
public class ResponseInterceptor implements ContainerResponseFilter{

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
            throws IOException {
        Object obj = responseContext.getEntity();
        // Modify the Response obj as per need
        responseContext.setEntity(obj);
    }
}
```